# C# S3 Bucket TransferUtilityDownloadRequest working but TransferUtilityDownloadDirectoryRequest does not

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, access-denied

I am using TransferUtilityDownload and TransferUtilityDownloadDirectory to download a file and full directrory. However even I am using same bucket name format it is working for single file but not for directory and returns 403 Access Denied. (same problem with listing objects):

```
        string bucketName = "my-bucket-us-east-1-prod";
        string UnscheduledIn = "abc/butter/input_butter_11nov2019/unscheduled";

        AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

        // request for object download
        var request = new TransferUtilityDownloadRequest(); 
        // request for directory download
        var drequest = new TransferUtilityDownloadDirectoryRequest();

        //This request for single file download
        request.BucketName = bucketName + "/" + UnscheduledIn;
        request.FilePath = "D:\\input\\" + "test.csv";
        request.Key = "test.csv";

        //This request for directory download
        drequest.BucketName = bucketName + "/" + UnscheduledIn;
        drequest.S3Directory = "unscheduled"; 
        drequest.LocalDirectory = "D:\\input\\";
        drequest.DownloadFilesConcurrently = true;

        TransferUtility fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(new AmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint.USEast1));

        // This one works
        fileTransferUtility.Download(request);

        // This one does not work
        fileTransferUtility.DownloadDirectory(drequest);
```

403 Access Denied error usually cause of wrong bucket or directory name (if request cannot find the bucket or directory and this is a known issue). However bucket name and directory name are correct. I wonder if the formatting or setting up some properties am missing?

Quick note this version also returns same 403 error:

```
               //This request for directory download
              drequest.BucketName = bucketName;
              drequest.S3Directory = UnscheduledIn; 
              drequest.LocalDirectory = "D:\\input\\";
              drequest.DownloadFilesConcurrently = true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks there is some issue with the bucket name and s3 directory path. Update your code with this piece of code.

```
//This request for directory download
drequest.BucketName = bucketName;
drequest.S3Directory = '/' + UnscheduledIn; 
drequest.LocalDirectory = "D:\\input";
drequest.DownloadFilesConcurrently = true;
```

**Update:**

In General, 403 forbidden comes from server in case of authentication failed/Permission Issue.
Please check your bucket policy to allow download.

```
    {
      "Sid": "AllowAllS3ActionsInUserFolder",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:*"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-us-east-1-prod/abc/butter/input_butter_11nov2019/*","arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-us-east-1-prod/abc/butter/input_butter_11nov2019/unscheduled/*"]
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately same result access denied - Web Exception: The remote server returned an error (403)

Comment: I have just update the answer, can you check your bucket policy.

Comment: Please read carefully, I am able to download using 

  **fileTransferUtility.Download(request);**

However problem is with 

   **fileTransferUtility.DownloadDirectory(drequest);**

So there is no policy issue.

Comment: Hi @JohnG i believe i read it carefully otherwise i would have propose you to check your access key or secret key. You are downloading directory which is a content of another (parent) directory and the files you are downloading are the contents of another (child) directory and bucket policy can be different for these directories, so just asked to check bucket policy of both the directories.

Comment: @Tinker Thank you for explanation. This is an EC2 box and yes we did check all policies are okay.

Comment: thank you after review I found out policy has a type so was not working. I am marking your answer.